# Typescript Function Not Found

Tags: typescript, screeps

Source code can be found here https://github.com/zevrant/screeps

I have an interface that is implemented by several classes, when i go to call the implemented interface i get the following error and i don't know why. I am a java developer and my only typescript experience is with Angular, so my knowledge of TypeScript is limited.

TypeError: spawn.memory.tasks[0].execute is not a function
at _.forEach.spawn  (../src/main.ts:70:30)

**Edit1**

logging the object

```
{"priority":10,"class":"SpawnCreep","outputs":{},"requirements":{},"sourceLocation":{"id":"2bdee70715ebc4e","room":{"name":"W3N7","energyAvailable":14,"energyCapacityAvailable":300,"visual":{"roomName":"W3N7"}},"pos":{"x":27,"y":16,"roomName":"W3N7"},"name":"Spawn1","energy":14,"energyCapacity":300,"spawning":{"name":"0u9tvotgf5cgw4ifhoewivg","needTime":15,"remainingTime":1},"store":{"energy":14},"owner":{"username":"Zevrant"},"my":true,"hits":5000,"hitsMax":5000,"structureType":"spawn"},"storageLocation":{"id":"2bdee70715ebc4e","room":{"name":"W3N7","energyAvailable":14,"energyCapacityAvailable":300,"visual":{"roomName":"W3N7"}},"pos":{"x":27,"y":16,"roomName":"W3N7"},"name":"Spawn1","energy":14,"energyCapacity":300,"spawning":{"name":"0u9tvotgf5cgw4ifhoewivg","needTime":15,"remainingTime":1},"store":{"energy":14},"owner":{"username":"Zevrant"},"my":true,"hits":5000,"hitsMax":5000,"structureType":"spawn"},"creep":{"id":"2bdee70715ebc4e","room":{"name":"W3N7","energyAvailable":14,"energyCapacityAvailable":300,"visual":{"roomName":"W3N7"}},"pos":{"x":27,"y":16,"roomName":"W3N7"},"name":"Spawn1","energy":14,"energyCapacity":300,"spawning":{"name":"0u9tvotgf5cgw4ifhoewivg","needTime":15,"remainingTime":1},"store":{"energy":14},"owner":{"username":"Zevrant"},"my":true,"hits":5000,"hitsMax":5000,"structureType":"spawn"}}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code is linked in an external site; Stack Overflow requires all code to be in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you store the class instance in the memory, it gets converted into
> a JSON representation, ie looses all the functions.

You will need to create an empty class and set the values and invoke the function.

`const spawnCreep = new SpawnCreep()`

assign `spawn.memory.tasks[0]` to `spawnCreep`

and call `spawnCreep.execute()`

Comment: but the name of the method is execute(), executeTask() does not exist

Comment: can u try logging `spawn.memory.tasks[0]` @Zevrant

Comment: i get [object Object]

Comment: i can access all of the class level objects fine just not any of the functions

Comment: can you try logging JSON.stringify(spawn.memory.tasks[0])